# Negative gradients with OpenCV Scharr operator

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using `Scharr` operator (an alternative to Sobel) for gradients computation. When I check the matrix (`Mat`) for gradients in x and y direction, all my gradients are positive.

Can anyone tell why I am not getting negative gradients?

Find below my code fragment.

```
//create Mat (matrix) for coloured image, gray_image, gradients in y and x directions
Mat image,gray_image, grad_y,grad_x; 

//read coloured to the program from a folder
 image = imread("image_path");
// convert coloured image to gray
cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// initialize image depth and scale
int ddepth=CV_16S;
int scale = 1;

//used scahrr operator to compute gradients in y direction
 Scharr(gray_image, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1,scale,BORDER_DEFAULT );


//used scahrr operator to compute gradients in x direction
 Scharr(gray_image, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0,scale,BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

Note: I also used other ddepth values such as CV32F, CV64F and CV_8UC1

Comment: How do you determine that you have only positive gradients? This code work ok for me (with negative gradients).